# DetailsView How to retrieve a DataKeyNames after an item has been inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a DetailsView control with `DataKeyNames="JobId"` (Primary Key for my DB table).

When a row has been inserted `OnItemInserted` I need to retrieve the JobId just created and use in some code.

I am not able to do it... Could you please post a easy example?

Comment: did you tried e.Values["JobId"] (remember to convert into type of your primary key before using) inside ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e) event.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a lot of usefull information regarding to this case: which database you have used, in which way you get the data and so on. So I can suggest you only take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx there is a lot of samples how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to Use DetailsView in association with a EntityDataSource.
An apply code in event OnItemInserted for the EntityDataSource instead that DetailsView.
So it is possible to cast an Entity to a Context Object and use the value JobId just created.
Hope can help someone else.